# Redis for multiple purposes

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis

I use Redis for handling user sessions on the server (ExpressJS). Now, I also want to use it for caching other data and managing job queues with bullmq. But I'm not sure if it's a good idea to mix everything in one redis server. Would it be better to have **separate Redis server for each purpose**(one redis server for user sessions, one for caching frequent data, one for bullmq) ? If there's another approach, could you explain it along with its pros and cons?

Thank you!